# Extracting street segments from google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api

I'm using the google maps v3 api and am trying to extract a list of intersections and street segments from an overlay created from a KML file.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to get the poly lines in a manner similar to the way Google Mapmaker works currently when you right click and go to 'find near this point'(http://www.google.com/mapmaker?hl=en)

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: depending on what you're going to do with the data, you might want to read over the Google Maps terms of use, as this could easily be the sort of thing that violates the license you agreed to in using the API.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I don't plan on brute forcing this or anything but I'll definately double check the TOS